# How can code duplication be avoided in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have many resources in `routes.rb` where many few resources are used and repeated.
*Is there a way to avoid code duplication?*

```
  resources :pages do
    resources :comments
    ##other routes 
    member { post :vote }   
  end 
  resources :videos do
    resources :comments
    ##other routes
    member { post :vote }   
  end 
  resources :images do
    resources :comments
    ##other routes 
    member { post :vote }   
  end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: If you were using Rails 4, you could use `concern` in your `routes.rb`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Concerns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can organize your routes file so as to keep it from becoming a massive, unmanageable mess. But, it's not via Concerns ... it's actually more "basic" than that. Just break up the files and include them in the main routes file :).

I read a good post on this a while back: [splitting routes,rb into smaller parts](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/02/how-to-split-routes-dot-rb-into-smaller-parts/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've used procs for this myself. Then I just call it in each namespace or resource block where I need it.

But concerns are likely a better and more readable solution.